# OS X - Eclipse - WindowBuilder -> "Incompatible Java versions"

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, jdk

No matter what I do, Eclipse keeps saying that "*Eclipse is running under 1.6, but this Java project has a 1.7 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project. Ues a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.*"

I spent two hours on this, so before I throw everything out, I thought I should ask you guys.
The system is an iMac with a 10.8.5 OS X.
Installed JDK 7 from Oracle. (`java -version` shows the version as 7.)
If I print it with Java, it prints 7.

Modified Eclipse settings (Compiler) to 7.
Used override in project settings to make it 7.
Modified eclipse.ini file so the -vm points to 7.

I'm out of ideas and patience. Both.

Update #1: System Preferences shows Java 7 as well.

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME set to?

Comment: To the new JDK. In the end I spent another few hours to install / remove eclipse workspaces, import project, install plugins and blah blah. In the end I made it work by launching the latest install from cli. But again, I don't know what worked.

Comment: Which Eclipse are you use? Helios, Juno or Kepler?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.  Below is how I solved it.

It looks like more work than it really is.  If I accidentally deleted a step trying to format all this text, let me know.

> First, on your Mac, you *should* find the "default Java from Apple" residing at:  */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java*

From the Eclipse menu: *Eclipse> Preferences> Java> Installed JRE's>*

- CLICK "*Add..*"
- SELECT "*Mac OS X VM*"
- CLICK "*Next..*"

In the 'JRE Definition dialog' that comes up,

- SELECT "*Directory..*" next to JRE Home,
- DRILL DOWN and SELECT */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/*.

Finish filling out what is needed, and then,

- SELECT *java 1.6* in *Eclipse> Preferences> Java> Installed JRE's>*
- SELECT *Eclipse> Preferences> Java> Installed JRE's> Execution Environment>*.
- CLICK on "*JavaSE-1.6*", 
  and make sure that your Java 1.6 Runtime you just set up is *checked*.

RIGHT CLICK on your *project folder* in the *workbench* to open your projects properties, and *double-check* that Java 1.6 is good to go under the "*Java Compiler*" menu and sub-menu's.

While *still* in your project's properties dialog:

- CLICK "*Run/Debug Settings*"
- SELECT your *project's name*,
- CLICK "*Edit..*"

In the resulting dialog, 'Edit launch configuration properties':

- CLICK the "*JRE*" tab and *ensure* it's Java 1.6
- SELECT the "*Classpath*" tab and *double check* that it also is including Java 1.6

In the '*Project Explorer*' tab, within your project, find the "*JRE System Library*" amongst your project's folders.  *Make sure* it say's *Java 1.6*

*if NOT:*

- RIGHT CLICK *it*
- SELECT "*Properties*"
- CHECK MARK "*Execution Environment*", and in the drop down menu, SELECT *JavaSE-1.6*

RE-START eclipse

I'll confess, it is late and I'm hurrying, so changing every reference from 1.7 to 1.6  I have it working as I write this.  In fact, I JUST got it working, so am sharing this before I get at it!

> The BELOW step I also did.  In my case, I was running Indigo  3.7 on Mac Mavericks.  If the above still isn't working, this is the other thing I added in my situation.

- RIGHT CLICK your actual *Eclipse icon*
- SELECT the "*Show Contents*" menu item.
- OPEN the "*Contents/*" folder
- *OPEN* the "*MacOS/*" folder
- OPEN "*eclipse.ini*" in a *text editor*.
- *ABOVE* the line that says "*-vm*" (without the quotes)
- *ADD* the line:  *-vm /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java*

This starts eclipse with Java 1.6, rather than the Java 1.7 that is now default on your system.  Obviously, you need to re-start eclipse after editing it's .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps
step-1
go to  the eclipse  window--> preference-->java--> compiler (serach java) we can get the compilercompliance level as let say 1.7

step-2
   chek the java version in the command prompt

$ java -version
get the below message 
java version "1.6.0_35"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.7) (6b35-1.13.7-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

so u can see the java version is mismatch

so open  the eclipse.ini  from the folder exist in the eclipse installable folder/

append  the jdk version 
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m